# How to run Spyder with Python 3.7 with Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, python-3.7

I have installed Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine which comes with Spyder and Python 3.6 but I wish to upgrade to Python 3.7

To create an Anaconda Environment with Python 3.7 is easy by using:

```
conda create --name py37 python=3.7
```

or:

```
conda create --name py370 python=3.7.0 --channel conda-forge
```

However starting Spyder in this environment will throw it back to Python 3.6. 
I tried specifing the python.exe (for version 3.7) directly in `Tools -> Settings` of Spyder, however upon restarting the Spyder Kernels can't be launched and will display that they need the packages: `ipykernel` and `cloudpickle` .

When trying to `conda install` them in the environment the following appears:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    python:           3.7.0-hea74fb7_0      --> 3.6.6-hea74fb7_0
```

Which would downgreade python from 3.7 to 3.6 again.

My final try was to use the command:

```
conda install python==3.7
```

which has failed with the output

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python-dateutil -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
  - python-dateutil -> six
  - python==3.7
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

The question is not how to upgrade Conda to Python 3.7, but how can I get Spyder to work with Python 3.7 in its own environment

Answer (score 16):

When you run `spyder` from the CMD/terminal, your operating system tries to find the spyder executable on your system's PATH.  In this case, it will default back to the base environment's version of spyder, which runs Python 3.6.

The best way I have found so far is to install spyder to the new environment; activate the environment, and then run spyder (which should fire up the version in the local environment).

```
conda create --name py37 python=3.7  
conda install --name py37 spyder -c conda-forge
conda activate py37
spyder
```

However, this requires the version of spyder to support python 3.7.  Currently that is not available (as of 2 July 2018), but it should not be too long coming.

**EDIT:**
Spyder for Python 3.7 is available.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so basically it is not possible atm?

Comment: Connecting spyder to different conda environments is an open issue.  People have found work-arounds, but none of them are stable as far as i can tell.  So you will likely have to wait until the 3.7 version of packages start rolling out.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) @Kev1n91, no, it's not possible at the moment because Anaconda has not released packages for Spyder and its dependencies for Python 3.7 yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we are really insterested in testing the new features, are there any information on how long it will take till Anaconda has released the required packages?

Comment: I have just tried this, and as of July 24 it works: there is a spyder version 3.3.0-py37_0 and spyder-kernels 0.2.4-py37_0 now available.

Comment: I always have kernel problem using Spyder 3.3.2 with Python 3.7.2. Downgrading Python to 3.6.8 fixed it

Comment: This still does not work I need to run Python 3.7, amd following the code below - it still launches Python 3.8.

Comment: @BenWatson check the location of where `spyder` is launching from using `where.exe spyder` (on Windows) or `which spyder` on linux.