# Anaconda fails after hanging on installing Spyder to a new environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, bz2

I have major trouble with (Ana)conda after trying to install Spyder to a new environment!
I created a new environment with `conda create -n py37 -c anaconda python=3.7`, but Anaconda was hanging when I tried to install Spyder to this environment.

According to [How to run Spyder with Python 3.7 with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139232/how-to-run-spyder-with-python-3-7-with-anaconda) this should be possible now.
After closing Anaconda the following problems occurred:

- Anaconda-Navigator fails to start
- If I try to update or install packages with Anaconda Prompt I get the following error:

  ```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
  ```
- If I try to run `conda info --envs` I get:

  ```
  An unexpected error has occurred
  ```

To me it seems like some dependencies are completely messed up!
I am working with Windows 7.

Comment: You're right, I think you broke your installation and need to reinstall Anaconda again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem for me is, I do not know how to remove it completely. I am afraid that when I simply remove the programm through Windows and reinstall Anaconda that I will mess it up even more. I would prefer to fully uninstall Anaconda using Anaconda-Clean, but I can't install the package. Any thoughts?